# How to retrieve list of File-pages referred to by subset of wikipages?

Tags: mediawiki

I want to get a list of all pages in the File-namespace which is referred to by a wikipages given in a list (I want to export a subset of pages including referred images).
Assume I've this pages (Page A_1 includes File:10.jpg and so on):

```
A_1 -> File:10.jpg
A_2 -> File:11.jpg
A_3 -> File:12.jpg File:20.jpg
B_1 -> File:13.jpg File:20.jpg
B_2 -> File:14.jpg
B_3 -> File:15.jpg
C_1 -> File:16.jpg
C_2 -> File:17.jpg File:12.jpg
C_3 -> File:19.jpg
```

So for pages B_1, B_2, B_3 this should give:

```
File:13.jpg, File:20.jpg, File:14.jpg and File:15.jpg
```

Is there some script or API-call to achieve this?
Thanks in advance for your hel

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the <s>[fileusage API](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bfileusage)</s> [images API](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bimages).

Comment: Thanks. But that's the other way around: which pages use a given File:-page.